# For each table of class 'y', if table does not contain descendant with class 'x', select th and td descendants

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

For each table of class 'y', if table does not contain descendant with class 'x', select descending th and td elements then remove their width attribute.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('table.y').has(':not(.x)').find('td').removeAttr('width')
    $('table.y').has(':not(.x)').find('th').removeAttr('width')
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `not` method and `:has` selector, for excluding elements, first you should use `not` method or `:not` selector.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('table.y').not(':has(.x)').find('td, th').removeAttr('width')
});
```